# Hide one div and show the other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create the following effect.

1. I have three `div`s: `div1`, `div2`, `div3`.
2. When I click on `div1`, it slides up and gets removed and, at the same time, `div2` slides up and becomes visible.
3. Similarly, when `div2` is clicked, `div2` slides up and gets removed and ,as `div2` is sliding up, `div3` starts sliding up becoming visible.

I am unable to figure out how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need an accordion widget.  Check this out https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 2):

This sample code acts on all divs. You can change selector to special class or IDs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
     $(this).slideUp().next("div").slideDown();
  });
})
```

in your case this is enough:

```
$("#div1").click(function(){$(this).slideUp();$("#div2").slideDown();
$("#div2").click(function(){$(this).slideUp();$("#div3").slideDown();
```

Comment: Yes, this would work but clicking on the last element would make it disappear. Using this approach you would have to add something like: if ($(this).is("div:last-of-type")) {$("div:first-of-type").slideDown(); }; to make it display the first div again. This is in no way the best way to approach the problem though.

Comment: Thank you. The question made no tries So I wrote a general answer. After your comment I added the case solution however this non-general solution is not appealing to me!

Comment: I agree. I don't know why the user would want iterate through div elements in this way. If you had more than 3 elements, what if you wanted to jump from, say, sixth to second. Personally I would go for an accordion approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using jQuery to do this.  In particular check out the `animate()` function.  Now there are many different ways to accomplish this effect and they will have different implementations depending on the outcome that is need.  I have a JSFiddle link following where I give you one such example.

In the example I have a wrapper `div` that has `overflow: hidden` applied to it to act as the "hiding bound".  Then I wrap the 3 `div`'s in a slide wrapper to allow for vertical sliding.  Then all I did was add a click event to the `#first` and `#second` `div`'s that move the `#slideWrapper` up by the appropriate margin's with an animated effect supplied by jQuery `$.animate()` function.  This should give you a good place to start.

https://jsfiddle.net/ph7ryon3/2/